# polyfills issues with Internet explorer 11 and angular HttpClient post

Tags: angular, typescript, httpclient, internet-explorer-11, polyfills

I'm having trouble getting my angular 4 application to work in IE 11 with the new httpclient post. This problem is only related to IE11 and is working fine in chrome.

I keep getting the error Invalid character.
[image]

From what I can see that differs is the post body that I send to the server. In the chrome browser it is formatted like this:

[image]

And in IE11 the same object is looking like this:

[image]

Can these Symbol properties mess up the object so that it wont be accepted on the server? If i dont parse the error message with an interceptor I just get Internal server error(500).

This is the object that I specify to send in the body:

let body =
{
                FromDate: form.fromDepDate,//Date 
                ToDate: form.toDepDate, //Date
                UserIds: userIds //string array 
            };

Comment: have you fixed it? i have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure that I understood what you asked. It looks like a problem many angular users are having with IE. This problem is that http requests actually go through but are seen as errors by angular because it cannot parse the server response (but you talk about 500s ? If you actually get 500 Internal Server Errors then it's most likely a problem with your backend)

If you don't get 500s but a behaviour suck as described above, this appears to be a bug on *IE11* (and maybe others) with angular 4+. It looks like HttpClient cannot parse empty 200 responses.

Bug is tracked on the [angular repo](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18680).

Although it was fixed in **angular 5.2.4**, if you can't or won't update, multiple workaround seem to work:

- One possibility is to change your server to return `204 No Content` instead of *200* when the response body is empty
- Another possible workaround is to use an HTTP interceptor to do the work [as compeek suggested](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18680).

This is my solution:

```
@Injectable()
export class EmptyResponseBodyInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
intercept(req: HttpRequest < any > , next: HttpHandler): Observable < HttpEvent < any >> {
    req = req.clone({
        responseType: 'text'
    });

    return next.handle(req)
        .map((res) => {
            if (res instanceof HttpResponse) {
                if (res.body === 'OK') {
                    res.clone({
                        body: null
                    });
                } else {
                    res = res.clone < any > ({
                        body: res.body !== '' ? JSON.parse(res.body) : null
                    });
                }
            }

            return res;
        });
}
```

}